# NpgsqlException: ERROR: 22P02: invalid input syntax for type json

Tags: postgresql, c#, npgsql

I have the following JSON string:

```
{"packedRecipeType":"DynamicCharacterAvatar","name":"Character","race":"HumanFemale","dna":[{"dnaType":"DynamicUMADna","dnaTypeHash":1932961400,"packedDna":"{\"bDnaAsset\":{\"instanceID\":108582},\"bDnaAssetName\":\"HumanFemaleDNA 1\",\"bDnaSettings\":[{\"name\":\"height\",\"value\":180},{\"name\":\"headSize\",\"value\":128},{\"name\":\"headWidth\",\"value\":57},{\"name\":\"neckThickness\",\"value\":128},{\"name\":\"armLength\",\"value\":128},{\"name\":\"forearmLength\",\"value\":128},{\"name\":\"armWidth\",\"value\":128},{\"name\":\"forearmWidth\",\"value\":128},{\"name\":\"handsSize\",\"value\":128},{\"name\":\"feetSize\",\"value\":128},{\"name\":\"legSeparation\",\"value\":128},{\"name\":\"upperMuscle\",\"value\":51},{\"name\":\"lowerMuscle\",\"value\":128},{\"name\":\"upperWeight\",\"value\":51},{\"name\":\"lowerWeight\",\"value\":128},{\"name\":\"legsSize\",\"value\":128},{\"name\":\"belly\",\"value\":128},{\"name\":\"waist\",\"value\":128},{\"name\":\"gluteusSize\",\"value\":128},{\"name\":\"earsSize\",\"value\":178},{\"name\":\"earsPosition\",\"value\":128},{\"name\":\"earsRotation\",\"value\":128},{\"name\":\"noseSize\",\"value\":96},{\"name\":\"noseCurve\",\"value\":115},{\"name\":\"noseWidth\",\"value\":102},{\"name\":\"noseInclination\",\"value\":128},{\"name\":\"nosePosition\",\"value\":134},{\"name\":\"nosePronounced\",\"value\":128},{\"name\":\"noseFlatten\",\"value\":134},{\"name\":\"chinSize\",\"value\":115},{\"name\":\"chinPronounced\",\"value\":134},{\"name\":\"chinPosition\",\"value\":204},{\"name\":\"mandibleSize\",\"value\":118},{\"name\":\"jawsSize\",\"value\":64},{\"name\":\"jawsPosition\",\"value\":137},{\"name\":\"cheekSize\",\"value\":96},{\"name\":\"cheekPosition\",\"value\":255},{\"name\":\"lowCheekPronounced\",\"value\":128},{\"name\":\"lowCheekPosition\",\"value\":255},{\"name\":\"foreheadSize\",\"value\":83},{\"name\":\"foreheadPosition\",\"value\":140},{\"name\":\"lipsSize\",\"value\":137},{\"name\":\"mouthSize\",\"value\":73},{\"name\":\"eyeRotation\",\"value\":124},{\"name\":\"eyeSize\",\"value\":121},{\"name\":\"breastSize\",\"value\":0},{\"name\":\"breastCleavage\",\"value\":149},{\"name\":\"eyeSpacing\",\"value\":150},{\"name\":\"green\",\"value\":214},{\"name\":\"red\",\"value\":255},{\"name\":\"blue\",\"value\":184}]}"}],"characterColors":[{"name":"Skin","colors":[197,118,90,255,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"Hair","colors":[84,71,57,255,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"Eyes","colors":[183,216,225,255,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"Undies","colors":[255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0]}],"wardrobeSet":[{"slot":"Eyes","recipe":"CatEyeWard"},{"slot":"Ears","recipe":"M_Elf_Ears"},{"slot":"Underwear","recipe":"FemaleUndies2"},{"slot":"Hair","recipe":"FemaleHair1"},{"slot":"Eyebrows","recipe":"FEyebrow1"},{"slot":"Eyelashes","recipe":"Fem_Eyelash"},{"slot":"Face","recipe":"FFace2"}],"raceAnimatorController":"UltimateCharacterControllerDemo"}
```

If I read it from a file and insert to postgreSQL this way:

```
    public static void testwrite(NpgsqlConnection conn)
{
        string acct = "account1";
        string char_name = "character";
        string dna = File.ReadAllText("./file.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
    using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO character_data (account_name, character_name, dna_and_equipment) VALUES (@p, @q, @r)";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@p", acct));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@q", char_name));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@r", NpgsqlDbType.Json) { Value = dna });
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
}
```

everything works fine. However, if I send as a string from my windows machine to my Linux server and try to insert from the server to the database on the same machine by:

```
public static IEnumerator Create_Char(string acct_name, string char_name, string DNA_wardrobe, Action<string> succ, Action<string> err)
    {
        string bad_register = "";
        if (char_name.Length >= 15 || char_name.Length <= 3 || char_name.Any(char.IsDigit) || char_name.Any(char.IsSymbol) || char_name.Contains(" "))
        {
            bad_register = "Please choose an account name having between 4 and 14 characters, letters only.";
            err(bad_register);
            yield break;
        }
        else if (badwords.Any(w => char_name.Contains(w)) || char_name.Any(char.IsSymbol))
        {
            bad_register = "Please choose an appropriate character name.";
            err(bad_register);
            yield break;
        }
        else
        {


            using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT character_name FROM character_data WHERE character_name = @q)";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@q", char_name));
                using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar()))
                    {
                        bad_register = "That character name is already chosen.";
                        err(bad_register);
                        conn.Close();
                        yield break;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        bad_register = "";
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO character_data (account_name, character_name, dna_and_equipment) VALUES (@n, @p, @q)";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@n", acct_name));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@p", char_name));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@q", NpgsqlDbType.Json) { Value = DNA_wardrobe });
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        succ(bad_register);
                        conn.Close();
                        yield break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the NpgsqlException: ERROR: 22P02: invalid input syntax for type json. Now, I know I'm leaving a lot out, but obviously, I can't post the entire program. If you need more information, please let me know.

The thing is, if I save to file on the server, after it has been converted to bytes and sent from the client and received on the server, I can use the first method of reading from file and inserting... In fact, I even did a bash "diff" command to see the difference between the two files, and there is no difference at all... I don't understand why one insert works and the other doesn't... The only thing I can think is encoding. Could that be the cause of the error? Is there something inherent in the JSON string that may cause this error? Could it be something else and I'm leaving out some pertinent information? If that's the case, I'll gladly edit and add as much as is needed.

I have the following postgres package on Ubuntu 18.04 server: postgresql-server-dev-10. The method testwrite is using the latest Npgsql driver from nuget, while the coroutine Create_Char is using a Unity3d variation of the driver.

Edit: I should mention that the JSON originates from a 3rd party. I have already contacted them, and they claim it is valid JSON, as any online JSON validator will agree. But, I just noticed something. The many slashes within the string which are escaping the double quotes are not present for each and every double quote. It gave me an idea to remove all of the slashes, and sure enough, it is not valid JSON without the slashes.

Comment: "However, if I send as a string from my windows machine to my Linux server" How is this done?  Is the sending from machine to machine part of the code snippet you included?

Comment: "In fact, I even did a bash "diff" command to see the difference between the two files" How do you use "diff" to compare files on two different machines?  However it is, what if you "cmp" instead?

Comment: @jjanes I'm using https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetUsingTransport.html which is essentially a framework for UDP. It would be quite difficult to provide a reproducible example, but it appears that all bytes are transferred effectively. I print(json_file) before sending it, and I write to file the transferred information on the other side. I then simply copied and pasted what was printed into a second file on the server in vim in my ssh shell. Those were the 2 files I used diff on and found no difference. cmp gives the same result as diff.